How to make the PDF size on screen consistent with its paper size in inches?
Here is a minimal example,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  left=0.15in,
  right=0.15in,
  top=0.05in,
  bottom=0.05in,
  paperheight=4.1in,
  paperwidth=2.3in,
  showframe
]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
When I was young, I forgot how to laugh in the cave of Trophonius;
when I was older, I opened my eyes and beheld reality, at which I
began to laugh, and since then, I have not stopped laughing. I saw
that the meaning of life was to secure a livelihood, and that its goal
was to attain a high position; that love’s rich dream was marriage
with an heiress; that friendship’s blessing was help in financial
difficulties; that wisdom was what the majority assumed it to be; that
enthusiasm consisted in making a speech; that it was courage to risk
the loss of ten dollars; that kindness consisted in saying, “You are
welcome,” at the dinner table; that piety consisted in going to
communion once a year. This I saw, and I laughed.

--Kierkegaard
\end{document}

Observe that the width and height of the paper are 2.3 in and 4.1 in.  But when I take a ruler and measure the output on the screen, it is way smaller.  Of-course I can zoom in and out.  But is there a way I can set the default size which appears on compile consistent with the size of paper in inches.
I use Skim to view the pdf if it matters.
I eventually want to convert the PDF to a PNG with the same dimensions and a PPI of 326. My TeX engine is LuaLaTeX.

this isn't a TeX question. it's not even the doing of your viewer, though the viewer has some influence. it's a function of your hardware, software, configuration etc. etc. assuming this is a mac, ask on a mac site. (otherwise, for linux, ask on your distro's site. etc.)

@scribe you can convert your pdf to png with image magick or similar tools. They let you adjust the resolution to whatever you need. See https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=4461#a4469 for some examples

And try a different pdf viewer. In other viewers, showing the pdf in its actual size usually works. Maybe skim can't deal with retina displays?
